# DropDownList Value not displayed when using knockout-kendo.js and breeze.js

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, breeze

I am using Ryan Niemeyer's Knockout-Kendo.js library and breeze.js. I'm having an issue with DropDownList. I have the DropDownList defined like this:

```
<p data-bind= "text: breezeEntityKO().FruitId">  </p> <!--just for debug-->
<input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: selectionOptions, dataValueField: 'FruitId', dataTextField: 'FruitDescription',  value: breezeEntityKO().FruitId}"></input>
```

and this is the view model

```
var ViewModel = function() {
this.breezeEntityKO = ko.observable();
//get a breezeEntity. One of the properties on the entity is FruitId
this.breezeEntityKO(breezeEntity); 

breezeEntityKo().FruitId(2) // set Initial selection to orange

this.selectionOptions = ko.observableArray([
    { FruitId: 1, FruitDescription: "apple" },
    { FruitId: 2, FruitDescription: "orange" },
    { FruitId: 3, FruitDescription: "banana" }
]);

this.selectedFruitId = ko.observable(2); // just for debug
};
```

When I change the value of FruitId the DropDownList remains blank. The correct value is shown in the debug text output and changes every time I change the value of breezeEntityKo().FruitId.

```
breezeEntityKo().FruitId(3) // this changes the value shown on the debug text line but not the drop down list
```

The only way I can get the DropDownList to show the correct value is using the knockout 'With' binding. When I use the 'with' binding the value is defined like this - value: $data.FruitId

```
<div  data-bind="with: breezeEntityKO">
    <input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: selectionOptions, dataValueField: 'FruitId', dataTextField: 'FruitDescription',  value: $data.FruitId}"></input>
</div>
```

This does the job. The dropdownlist displays the correct value. Every time I change breezeEntityKo().FruitId the DropDownList updates. When I use the drop-down list to change the value of the FruitId property on the breezeEntity correctly changes. So all good. 
But, I'm having some performance issues when I use the knockout 'With' binding in this scenario, so if it's possible I'd like to find an alternative.

Any ideas as to how I could use the kendoDropDownList where 'value' comes from a property on a breeze entity without having to wrap everything in a 'With'?

The documentation is here https://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/DropDownList.html

There is no problem when 'Value' is just a ko.observable as per the example in the documentation. I'm just running into issues when I try to define 'value' as breezeEntityKO().FruitId or breezeEntityKO.FruitId

**Edit**
 The following works without any issues but I need it to work with breezeEntityKO.FruitId rather than selectedFruitId

```
<input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: selectionOptions, dataValueField: 'FruitId', dataTextField: 'FruitDescription',  value: selectedFruitId}"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to try so that the options won't get re-rendered:

```
this.selectedFruitId = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.breezeEntityKo().FruitId();
}, this);
```

Then use what you have in your Edit as the markup:

```
<input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: selectionOptions, dataValueField: 'FruitId', dataTextField: 'FruitDescription',  value: selectedFruitId}"></input>
```

Here's the previous answer before the question edits:

Haven't used knockout-kendo, but generally I find the `with` binding the best and most efficient way to do this. As an alternative, you should be able to do the following:

```
<input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: breezeEntityKO().selectionOptions, dataValueField: 'FruitId', dataTextField: 'FruitDescription',  value: breezeEntityKO().FruitId}"/>
```

Also, just a note: you don't need to use `$data` inside a with binding unless you actually need the whole object: scope is implied to be the context of the item you used in the `with` binding. So above you could say: `value: FruitId`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated my question with some extra details. The selectionOptions were getting picked up correctly its just 'value' isn't getting set when I try breezeEntityKO().FruitId or breezeEntityKO.FruitId. The reason i'm trying to avoid the 'With' is so that all the selectionOptions are not rerendered everytime I change the entity in breezeEntityKo(). I have a form with about 50 of these drop downs and some have a few hundred options available.

Comment: Are the selected options static for each of the 50ish dropdown? If so, I'd say define those on a parent object, and the using `with` you could reference them with the `$parent` binding.. i.e. `data: $parent.selectionOptions`.

Comment: Yes, they are static for each of the drop downs. Even if i use data: $parent.selectionOptions wont this still sit within the scope of data-bind="with: breezeEntityKO"? If there is a change to breezeEntityKO wont this re render everything including the $parent.selectionOptions? What i'm trying to achieve is that when I change the entity that is in breezeEntityKO it only changes the value of the dropdown and it doesn't re render all the selectionOptions as well.

Comment: It may re-render, not honestly sure without testing it out. I updated my answer to reflect the updated info. See if that helps at all = )